# How to convert JQuery to Pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, converters

please help me how to convert the JQuery script into pure Javascript? I'm beginner in this PL.
Thank you

Here's the JQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('address').each(function () {
    var link = "<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent( $(this).text() ) + "'  target='_blank'>" + $(this).text() + "</a>";
    $(this).html(link);
});
});
```

[Here's the link for output of JQuery script](http://jsbin.com/cowafaqa/1/edit)

Comment: If you understand what the code does, you should be able to do this yourself with no difficulty. If you don't understand what the code does, there's a larger problem here that should be addressed first.

Comment: ... and what have you tried so far?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a code translation service.

Comment: mmm, why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var ele = document.querySelectorAll("address");
    for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++){
        var link = "<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent( ele[i].innerText ) + "'  target='_blank'>" + ele[i].innerText + "</a>";
        ele[i].innerHTML = link;
    }
});
```

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - Oh! Didn't see those. Thanks.